# Exit a while loop using KeyListener

Tags: java, while-loop, keylistener

I'm trying to make my own Autoclicker and can't figure out how to exit the "clicking" using a KeyListener. I get that a part of the problem is that the window needs to be in focus for a KeyListener to work, but I've got no clue on how to implement that.

I'll add all the code so you can see for yourself on how to solve it.

```
public class GUIMain extends JFrame {
protected static GUIMain window = null;
protected static Box mainFrame = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
protected Click clicker = null;

public GUIMain(String title) {
    super(title);
    mainBox();
    startRunning();

    this.addKeyListener(clicker);
    this.toFront();
    this.pack();
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    window = new GUIMain("AutoClicker v0.1");
}

protected void mainBox() {
    this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this.getContentPane(), 
            BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    mainFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 150));
    this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    this.add(mainFrame);
    mainFrame.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
}

protected void startRunning() {
    JButton startButton = new JButton(" Start ");
    mainFrame.add(startButton);
    mainFrame.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
    startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            clicker = new Click();
        }
    });

}
}
```

and now the "Click" class that implements the KeyListener. 
I've got the i<100 part in the while loop just so that it doesn't loop forever while fixing it.

```
public class Click extends JComponent implements KeyListener{
private static boolean runClicks = true;
static Robot robot = null;

public Click() {
    mouseClick();
}

protected static void mouseClick() {
    int i = 0;
    try {
        robot = new Robot ();
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while(runClicks && i < 100) {
            click(-1440, 540);
            i++;
    }
}

private static void click(int x, int y) {
    robot.mouseMove(x, y);
    robot.delay(50);
    robot.mousePress(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
    robot.mouseRelease(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F9) {
        runClicks = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {  
}
}
```

Do I need to think of a new way to solve this or can it be done with some modifications?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Java expert by any means, but if you need to give the window focus, you can use the requestFocus() call.

```
public static void main(string[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add // whatever you want to add to your frame and sizing
    frame.requestFocus();
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that it will loose the focus every time the mouse preforms a click. Although, maybe I can add the requestFocus in the while-loop so that it gets the focus everytime it gets looped through.